# alpha tubulin molecular weight problem

Tags: biochemistry, homework, proteins

Is there any academic reference that shows α-tubulin is around 50-55 kDa? The only thing I found is some data sheets from companies. I need the real reference.

Comment: The data sheet is a good enough reference. They must have showed a gel picture also. If not then find details of the protein in Uniprot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paper titled [Identification of α-tubulin as a granzyme B substrate during CTL-mediated apoptosis](http://jcs.biologists.org/content/119/5/858.full) mentions it as 51KDa and the paper titled [Carboxy-terminal amino acid sequence of α-tubulin from porcine brain](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v282/n5737/abs/282423a0.html) mentions it as 55,000 Da. Hope that suffices.

Answer (score 3):

This is not so easy to answer, since alpha-tubulin has at 10 known genes in this family (data from [Ensembl](http://www.ensembl.org/Homo_sapiens/Gene/Family/Genes?cdb=compara;db=core;family=ENSFM00250000000217;g=ENSG00000167552;r=12:49578579-49583107)):

- TUBA1A   tubulin, alpha 1a
- TUBA1B   tubulin, alpha 1b
- TUBA3E   tubulin, alpha 3e
- TUBA3D   tubulin, alpha 3d
- TUBA4A   tubulin, alpha 4a
- TUBAL3   tubulin, alpha-like 3
- TUBA1C   tubulin, alpha 1c
- TUBA3C   tubulin, alpha 3c
- TUBA8    tubulin, alpha 8
- TUBAL3   tubulin, alpha-like 3

You can go on the site linked above and choose any of the proteins. I checked [TUBA1A](http://www.ensembl.org/Homo_sapiens/Transcript/ProteinSummary?db=core;g=ENSG00000167552;r=12:49578579-49583107;t=ENST00000301071), and get a length of 451 amino acids and a weight of approximately 50,1 kDa.